# Is dry cottonwood safe for an aquarium?

Tags: fish, shrimp

I have a river close to my house with huge cotton woods growing along it. During monsoons they fall and dry out. I found some nice bits and I just want to know if I can soak them and add them to my aquarium.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! I do not know this special wood. But in general you should "cook" parts out of the nature before putting them into the aquarium. So you prevent to take bacteria or other animal beings into the tank too. (Took a fish from a pond into my aquarium and he brought some parasites with it...)

Comment: According to the Wikipedia disambiguation page, there are several kinds of cotton wood. Some might float (which is not useful), some might be poisonous for your little submerged friends. You need to be more specific about what you have there.